# Kafka Streams RocksDB large state

Tags: events, apache-kafka, stream, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

Is it okay to hold large state in RocksDB when using Kafka Streams? We are planning to use RocksDB as an eventstore to hold billions of events for ininite of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can store a lot of state there but there are some considerations:

- The entire state will also be replicated on the changelog topics, which means your broker will need to have enough disk space for it. Note that this will NOT be mitigated by KIP-405 (Tiered Storage) as tiered storage does not apply for compacted topics.
- As @OneCricketeer mentioned, rebuilding the state can take a long time if there's a crash. However, you can mitigate it via multiple ways:

  - Use a persistent store and re-start the application on a node with access to the same disk (StatefulSet + PersistentVolume in K8s works).

    - In exactly-once semantics, until KIP-844 is implemented upon an unclean shutdown the state will still be rebuilt from scratch. But once that PR is merged then only a small amount of data will have to be replayed.
  - Have standby replicas. They will enable failover as soon as the consumer session timeout expires once the kafka streams instance crashes.

Comment: Thank you, i think statefull sets can help to solve the state restoration problem. And with KIP-844 state restoration will be reduced drastically on unclean shutdowns. I hope KIP-844 is activelyy developed.

Answer (score 1):

The main limitation would be disk space, so sure, it can be done, but if the app crashes for any reason, you might be waiting for a while for the app to rebuild its state.

Comment: Thnx for your reply. Does restoration always occur when the app crashes? Even when i use a persistent state store?

Comment: It should, because there's no guarantee the state store holds the latest offsets from the topic